# cannot delete row while comparing column against multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete a row if one column is of a specific value, and if the other column is NOT any of the values provided (multiple values), but I get an error saying I have a problem in my sql syntax.

code:

```
$q = "DELETE FROM product_attributes WHERE product_id='$mpa' AND attribute_id NOT IN '$val_ids'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```

and this is what `$q` looks like when echoed:

```
DELETE FROM product_attributes WHERE product_id='2' AND attribute_id NOT IN '5,6'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change query like

```
$q = "DELETE FROM product_attributes WHERE product_id='$mpa' AND attribute_id NOT IN ($val_ids)";
```

Your query must be like

```
  DELETE FROM product_attributes WHERE product_id='2' AND attribute_id NOT IN (5,6)
```

Correct form of `NOT IN` is

```
       NOT IN (values)
```

You will get more details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `FIND_IN_SET` when values are in the form of CSV.

```
$val_ids = "5,6";  
$q = "DELETE FROM product_attributes 
      WHERE product_id='$mpa' 
        AND FIND_IN_SET( attribute_id, '$val_ids' )=0";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```

**Refer to**:

- [**FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)
  Return the index position of the first argument within the second argument.